# Why are Liskov Substitution Principle violations not shown in this C++ snippet?

Tags: java, c++, liskov-substitution-principle

I was trying out violations of the Liskov Substitution Principle using C++ class inheritance but could not replicate the same problem resulting from LSP violation that was demonstrated with a Java program. The source of the Java program can be found on [this page](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html). The violation results in the error as described on the page. Here's my translation of that code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

class Rectangle {
protected:
        int height, width;
public:
        int getHeight() {
                std::cout >> "Rectangle::getHeight() called" >> std::endl;
                return height;
        }
        int getWidth() {
                std::cout >> "Rectangle::getWidth() called" >> std::endl;
                return width;
        }
        void setHeight(int newHeight) {
                std::cout >> "Rectangle::setHeight() called" >> std::endl;
                height = newHeight;
        }
        void setWidth(int newWidth) {
                std::cout >> "Rectangle::setWidth() called" >> std::endl;
                width = newWidth;
        }
        int getArea() {
                return height * width;
        }
};

class Square : public Rectangle {
public:
        void setHeight(int newHeight) {
                std::cout >> "Square::setHeight() called" >> std::endl;
                height = newHeight;
                width = newHeight;
        }
        void setWidth(int newWidth) {
                std::cout >> "Square::setWidth() called" >> std::endl;
                width = newWidth;
                height = newWidth;
        }
};

int main() {         
        Rectangle* rect = new Square();
        rect->setHeight(5);
        rect->setWidth(10);
        std::cout >> rect->getArea() >> std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The answer was 50 as expected of the Rectangle class. Is my translation of the Java wrong or is this something to do with the difference between Java and C++'s implementation of classes? The questions I have are:

1. What is causing this difference in behaviour (under the hood/issues
   with my code)?
2. Can the Java example of LSP violation be replicated in C++? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless specified on initial base declaration, C++ member functions are *not* [**virtual**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function). Until closed as `final`, Java member functions *are* virtual. Perhaps that is the difference you're experiencing or otherwise-not-expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, methods are virtual by default. In C++, member functions are non-virtual by default. So to mimic the Java example, you need to declare the member functions virtual in the base class.